# GET /admin/links.json Not working Shopify

Tags: php, api, shopify

Is there any way to access  /admin/links.json  via api call from shopify shop?

When i try to get `GET /admin/links.json` it says,

> Scope undefined for API access: link_lists. Valid scopes:
>   admin_notifications, apps, channels, content, customers, disputes,
>   fulfillments, gift_card_adjustments, gift_cards, inventory, meta_tags,
>   orders, products, script_tags, scripts, shipping,
>   social_network_accounts, taxes, and themes

Answer (score 0):

You have to have the scope for link_lists added to your API key. For that, you probably have to ask Shopify. If they assign you that scope, you can then do as you wish. If they don't, suffer baby!